# Insert % character in the middle of the string in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

My Code snippet below,(running from Jenkins)

```
def mainUrl = "http://localhost:8080/job/"
...
jobsName.each(){
  println "Jobs: ${it}"
  println "${mainUrl}${it}/config.xml"
}
```

Which gives output like below:

```
Jobs: Env_test
Jobs: Dev_test
Jobs: Model test
Jobs: Prod test
```

I'm trying to replace the space character with % and used replaceAll method too, still no luck.

```
println "${mainUrl}${it}.replaceAll("//s","%")/config.xml"
```

Output I got:

> http://localhost:8080/job/Model test.replaceAll(
>
> http://localhost:8080/job/Prod test.replaceAll(

I'm looking for a Output like,

```
http://localhost:8080/job/Model%test/config.xml
http://localhost:8080/job/Prod%test/config.xml
```

Any suggestions . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
println "${mainUrl}${it}".replaceAll("\\s","%") + "/config.xml"
```

Taking this apart, it means:

- join `mainUrl` and `it` (you missed a double quote char after `{it}`),
- replace each space (regex reguires a **backslash** (not forward slash), but here it should be doubled),
- and add `/config.xml`, but as a **separate** string.

Comment: Many Thanks, silly mistake on missing double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
println "${mainUrl}${it.replaceAll('\\s','%')}/config.xml"
```

Comment: Great, worked perfect.+1 for ${it.replaceAll('\\s','%')}
Cant accept the answer one more time :(